# Hibernate Insert if record does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

How can I do this with Hibernate - If record does not exists insert it.

I have the following columns

Id (Primary Key),
Ticker Symbol,
Ticker Name,
Industry,
Sector,
LastUpdate

I would like to check the records at Ticker Symbol Column if the string exist don't do anything if it does not exist then insert a new row with Id, Ticker Symbol, Ticker Name, Industry, Sector and Update Date (today's date).

I have gone as far as creating a new Table with the code below.

```
//Hibernate Create a Session Factory    
 SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();         
 for (int i = 0; i < Bloomberg.getTickerSymbol().size(); i++){

            //Hibernate to store Stock Tickers Data     
        tickerInfo.setTickerSymbol(Bloomberg.getTickerSymbol().get(i)); //Symbol
        tickerInfo.setTickerName(Bloomberg.getTickerName().get(i)); //Name
        tickerInfo.setTickerSector(Bloomberg.getTickerSector().get(i)); //Sector
        tickerInfo.setTickerIndustry(Bloomberg.getTickerIndustry().get(i)); //Industry
        tickerInfo.setTickerLastUpdate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); //Update Date

        org.hibernate.Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(tickerInfo);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 //Hibernate Create a Session Factory    
 SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();         
for (int i = 0; i < Bloomberg.getTickerSymbol().size(); i++){

        //Hibernate to store Stock Tickers Data     
    tickerInfo.setTickerSymbol(Bloomberg.getTickerSymbol().get(i)); //Symbol
    tickerInfo.setTickerName(Bloomberg.getTickerName().get(i)); //Name
    tickerInfo.setTickerSector(Bloomberg.getTickerSector().get(i)); //Sector
    tickerInfo.setTickerIndustry(Bloomberg.getTickerIndustry().get(i)); //Industry
    tickerInfo.setTickerLastUpdate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); //Update Date

    org.hibernate.Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    List tickerInfos = session.createCriteria(TickerInfo.class).add(Restrictions.eq("tickerSymbol", Bloomberg.getTickerSymbol().get(i))).list();
   if(tickerInfos.size()<1){
         session.beginTransaction(); 
         session.saveOrUpdate(tickerInfo);
         session.getTransaction().commit();
   }
 }
session.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to create a unique constraint in your database, attempt the update, and catch the exception if the constraint is violated.

A better approach might be a mix this with a local cache of known added ticker symbols (assuming symbols are never removed), which should cut down to the amount of database calls being made.

Comment: You shouldn't control program flow with exceptions.  Item 57 in Chapter 9 of Effective Java by Joshua Bloch

Comment: I think that depends on what case is exceptional. If it doesn't exist 99% of the time then we are good to catch exceptions. For example optomistic checking. In addition one of the arguments against exceptions is because of the overhead, this is nothing compared to having to perform 2 database calls.

Comment: @samblake Good point, but it works rather poorly if you are inserting a set of records containing some that exist and some that do not